# Facebook app youtube video on a movie object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an action called 'watched' defined on an object 'Movie' (using the inbuilt object). The 'Movie' object requires a param called movie which is a required parameter. When I send a link to this movie as {movie:'http://www.movieurl.com'} it works good. But I wanna send a youtube video which gets embedded on the timeline.

```
When I use the object 'Video', embedding a youtube video works. But that would come in the feed as
```

'John Doe watched a video *_*_ on MyApp' 
       Embedded YouTube video here

Instead of that can I have:
    'John Doe watched a movie *_*_ on MyApp'
       Embedded YouTube video here

Thank you ..

Comment: I don't think that you can do that, if you look at the source code of youtube video pages you'll see that it uses `og:type=video`. If you use youtube you'll probably need to do it their way.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for your answer Nitzan :) Appreciate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change the name of the object type in the way you're describing